# How to generate random number and put it into string

Tags: php, random

Here is my working PHP code that fetches the data from Yahoo API.

```
<?php
$dom->strictErrorChecking = false;
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load( 'http://answers.yahooapis.com/AnswersService/V1/questionSearch?appid=appid&query=cats&region=us&type=resolved&start=200&results=1' );

$Question = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "Question" );
foreach( $Question as $Question )
{
$Subject = $Question->getElementsByTagName( "Subject" );
$Subject = $Subject->item(0)->nodeValue;

$Content = $Question->getElementsByTagName( "Content" );
$Content = $Content->item(0)->nodeValue;

$ChosenAnswer = $Question->getElementsByTagName( "ChosenAnswer" );
$ChosenAnswer = $ChosenAnswer->item(0)->nodeValue;

echo "<p><b>$Subject\n</b><br>$Content<br><i>$ChosenAnswer</i></p>";
}
?>
```

What I need to happen is at the end of the url where I have the number 200 in now, I need that to be a random number between 1 and 500. So when the php page is loaded that url in $doc->load will some times be start=245 then next page load might be start=365 and so on. So basically each page load is fetching a different url from Yahoo API. How do I add to my code here to create that random number?

Comment: RTLM: http://php.net/rand

Comment: Have you googled for "[php random](https://www.google.ca/search?q=php+random&aq=f&oq=php+random&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)" yet?

Answer (score 2):

Check `rand()`, I guess it will do the job:

```
rand(min,max):
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
$doc->load( 'http://answers.yahooapis.com/AnswersService/V1/questionSearch?appid=appid&query=cats&region=us&type=resolved&start=' . rand(1, 500) . '&results=1' );
```

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to read the forbidden book called `Documentation`, in this book you can find some mystical tips for make magical stuffs like `Random numbers between range`.

That trick is called `rand`, for use that trick:

```
$randomNumber = rand(1, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it just like that:

```
$random = mt_rand(1,500);

$doc->load( 'http://answers.yahooapis.com/AnswersService/V1/questionSearch?appid=appid&query=cats&region=us&type=resolved&start=' . $random . '&results=1' );
```

I used `.` (dot) operand to "add" strings here.

Simplified version easy to understand:

```
 $x = 5;

 $some_string = 'foo' . $x . 'bar'; // will produce text: foo5bar

 echo $some_string;
```